# Routing in Meteor ≥ 1.0

Tags: meteor

There are lots of routing related questions for earlier Meteor releases on SO, but where are we at in terms of best practices for basic routing in Meteor version ≥ 1.0?

I’ve previously used 3rd party packages such as Iron Router, Meteor-Router etc. From my understanding however, I could now achieve the same results by using the webapp package (https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/webapp) that I get ”for free” when running *meteor create myRoutableApp*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folks I've talked to that know far more than I do have indicated that Iron Router is the way to go. It's been updated for 1.0 and has a ton of really cool features.

In terms of using webapp, the documentation states that webapp can only function on the server side, which limits it to exposing your application's data to external HTTP requests. It's useful for creating an API that others can access, but it's not actually going to be useful to let people navigate around your app from the client side of things.